# Windows 7: You might need to sign up with this network's Internet service provider (ISP) to get access to the Internet

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

I've recently been receiving this message even though I'm connected to the internet. this has happened on my home laptop, and now my work PC. Could it be because of additional network adapters like VirtualBox Host-Only adapter?

It should be noted the message in the title is what I receive when I run the troubleshooter.  My network icon in the try has a yellow triangle and states I have no internet access which is untrue.

Comment: does this message appear when you visit a certain website? Also, which web browser are you using?

Comment: No, when I start the PC, the message center tells me I may need to log in using my web browser (not exact words).  The network icon has a yellow warning triangle.  When I mouse over, it shows my LAN connection and states "No Internet Access"  I'm using the affected PC right now to post this comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

confirm that you can get to http://www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt. MS uses this file to determine whether your computer is online.

see this blog entry to learn about how windows determines whether you are on the internet or not: http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/16/windows-7-network-awareness/

Note that your issue is likely DNS resolution. if you run 
`nslookup www.msftncsi.com` do you get a legit response? if not, try changing your hosts DNS address (Network Connection -> Internet Protocol Version 4) to 8.8.8.8 or 4.4.4.2 and see if you can resolve then. its possible that your router has configured your client to use it as the DNS server, and is not correctly processing the request.

Comment: Access Denied to http://www.msftncsi.com/.  Could this be why?  If so, why is it just happening now?  I suppose I'll just disable it via the internet, or maybe redirect to our web server via the blog post instructions.  Thanks!  I'll upvote when I have more rep points.

Comment: yes, it seems like that would be why the troubleshooter thinks you need to subscribe to an ISP, or login to their service if you already have it. I can confirm that the file is available to me, as of 10 seconds ago.

Comment: Edited my comment after you posted.